# How do I use camera in app to search for similar products?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am making an app in which by clicking image of an object of some colour for example white colour the matching colours can be find out (like what flipkart app has) [image need to be clicked for which relevant colours to be find out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AUIq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) to identify the object in the image and then you can search it.